# Discord.js Per Server Prefix Error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of null"

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hi i was making a per server prefix thing for my discord.js v12 bot using quick.db everything was going well but when using a command it throws this error

```
C:\Users\Aoshey\Desktop\Taco Bot V2\tacobot.js:50
        let prefix = db.get(`prefix_${message.guild.ID}`);
                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of null
```

i don't quite understand since i'm new to coding so sorry if it was something stupid
the main bot file's code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    let prefix = db.get(`prefix_${message.guild.ID}`);
    if(prefix === null) prefix = default_prefix;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `${message.author}, wrong usage`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }



    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command! Please tell Aro#1221 about this.');
    }
});
```

i noticed that the error only occurs when its used on only 1 command meanwhile other commands work well (also yes i'm using the command in a guild)
the code for the command which causes the error i think?

```js
const fsn = require("fs-nextra");
const colors = require("colors");



module.exports = {
    name: 'deleteorder',
    description: 'deleting/denying an order.',
    args: 'true',
    usage: '<order id> <reason>',
    aliases: ['od', 'delorder', 'do'],
    execute(message, args) {
        

        if (message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === '745410836901789749')) {
            let ticketID = args[0];
            let reason = args[1];

            fsn.readJSON("./orders.json").then((orderDB) => {
                const order = orderDB[ticketID];

                if(order === undefined) {
                    message.reply(`Couldn't find order \`${args[0]}\` Try again.`);

                    return;
                }

                if(reason === "") {
                    reason = "None Provided";
                }

                delete orderDB[ticketID];

                fsn.writeJSON("./orders.json", orderDB, {
                    replacer: null,
                    spaces: 4
                });

                message.reply(`You deleted order \`${args[0]}\` with reason \`${args[1]}\``)
                // Sends a message to the customer.
                let customer = message.guild.members.cache.find(m => m.id === order.userID)
                //message.users.cache.get(order.userID).send(`Sorry, but your order was cancelled by **${message.author.username}** due to the following reason: \`${reason}\`.`);
                customer.send(`Sorry, but your order was cancelled by **${message.author.username}** due to the following reason: \`${reason}\`.`)

                // Logs in console.
                console.log(colors.red(`${message.author.username} deleted order ${order.orderID}.`));


            });

        } else {
            message.reply("You aren't an employee.");
            console.log(colors.red(`${message.author.username} did not have access to the delorder command.`));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its just `id` in lowercase letters. `ID` in uppercase letters doesn't exist.

```js
let prefix = db.get(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`);
```

Comment: still keeps throwing the same error
"C:\Users\Aoshey\Desktop\Taco Bot V2\tacobot.js:50
        let prefix = db.get(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)
                                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null"
the command that was used works normally but throws the error which crashs the bot
other commands work normally and don't give any error idk why this command gives one

Comment: hm okay that means that `message.guild` is `null`

Comment: but how do i fix that? I'm using the command in a guild i don't know why is it "null"

Comment: console log `message.guild` when using the command and tell me the output

Comment: i put `console.log(message.guild)` and it flooded the console with guild informations like roles ids and member ids and channel ids it won't fit to put all these into a comment do you want me to take a picture?

Comment: No thanks I know how this looks like, but then it is not null, if there are informations about the guild displayed. But why does the error say that?

Comment: Can you please console log `prefix` as well?

Comment: it returns "undefined" in the console

Comment: Okay and the guild you are using the command in has the default prefix?